# How do I settle Havarl?

Tags: mass-effect-andromeda

I just opened the vault and raised the viability of the planet to 80%, the lead scientists there said we could go ahead and set up a outpost, but I can't seem to figure out where I can do that.

There are no icons on my map that marks a suitable outpost location.

Here is the my map:

[image: havarl map]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just leave to the tempest and check your email. I was stuck on this too.

Comment: it's similarly clunky for kadara as well, you have to finish a mission on kadara and then reboard the tempest to get an email to leave the tempest to settle on kadara...

Answer (score -2):

You can't put an outpost on Havarl, it won't let you.

Comment: You can't quite do a full outpost, but you can send some scientists down permanently to join the Angaran group.